# React-Router-DOM | URL gets redirected to the root Path

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router-v4, redux-observable

I have set an AppRouter with React-Router-DOM. Version 4. I have a table with Links attached to them, and I fetch data from the server, for each one. I want to see the details screen, of each item, when I click the Link in the table. That doesn't work.

**Below is the AppRouter**, which is the Router for the Application. All other routes are working perfectly FYI:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropsTypes from 'prop-types';
import { withProps } from 'recompose';
import ReactRouterPropTypes from 'react-router-prop-types';
import { Route, Switch, Redirect, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import { Authorization } from 'util/viewPermissionUtil';
import { Permission } from 'util/permissionsUtil';
import permissions from 'constants/roles';

import GroupDetailsScreen from 'GroupDetailsScreen';
import GroupsScreen from 'GroupScreen';
import UsersScreen from 'containers/UserScreen';

const GetUser = Authorization(({ user }) =>
  Permission(user, [permissions.somepermission])
);

const AuthUsers = GetUser(
  ({ ...props }) => <UsersScreen {...props} />,
  () => <Redirect to="/" />
);

const GetGroupsDetails = Authorization(({ user }) =>
  Permission(user, [permissions.someOtherPermissions])
);

const AuthGroupDetails = GetGroupsDetails(
  ({ ...props }) => <GroupDetailsScreen {...props} />,
  () => <Redirect to="/" />
);

const UsersRoute = ({ user }) => withProps({ user })(AuthUsers);
const GroupDetailsRoute = ({ user }) => withProps({ user })(AuthGroupDetails)

const Router = ({ match: { path }, user }) => (
  <Switch>
    <Route path={`${path}/groups`} component={GroupsScreen} />
    <Route path={`${path}/groups/details/:name`} component={GroupDetailsRoute({ user })} />
    <Route path={`${path}/users`} component={UsersRoute({ user })} />
    <Redirect to={`${path}/users`} />
  </Switch>
);

Router.propTypes = {
  match: ReactRouterPropTypes.match.isRequired,
  user: PropsTypes.object
};

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    user: state.auth.user
  };
}

const ConnectedRouter = connect(mapStateToProps)(Router);
const AppRouter = withRouter(({ ...props }) => <ConnectedRouter {...props} />);

export default AppRouter;
```

**In the TableConfig Component**, which is the configuration file for the Table columns:

```
function groupNameRenderer(cell, row) {
  return (
    <span className="text-align-left">
      <Link
        to={{
          pathname: `/groups/details/${row.name}`
        }}
      >
        {cell}
      </Link>
    </span>
  );
}

export const columns = [
  {
    dataField: 'name',
    sort: false,
    text: 'Group',
    formatter: groupNameRenderer,
  },
  {
    dataField: 'field',
    sort: true,
    text: 'FIELD'
  },
  {
    dataField: 'someField',
    sort: true,
    text: 'SOME FIELD'
  }
];
```

**In the Service file**, which makes the endpoint call to the server:

```
import { endpointInstance } from 'services/httpFactory';
import httpMethod from 'constants/httpMethod';

import endpoint from './endpoint';

export const getGroup = name => {
  const options = {
    method: httpMethod.GET,
    url: endpoint.GET_GROUP(name)
  };
  return endpointInstance(options);
};
```

I mean what is the problem here. I really don't get it at all. I tried a few different scenarios.

I try manually inserting a BrowserRouter in the AppRouter, although, the Router is set higher in the App chain, `DIDN'T WORK`.

I tried, manually inserting the endpoint data, as a constant file. Without making an API call, `DIDN'T WORK`.

I get the `URL`, changing for a single second, but on refresh, it does go back to `/`. I am really stumped. I implemented the same architecture in 2 different instances with the same methodology. Worked perfectly. Exactly the same.

My App is built on `React/Redux/Redux-Observable`, for asynchronous operations. On another note. I also pass the `getGroup` Service, to my `GroupDetailsScreen` to fetch either data or an error message, but the problem is with the router. I get the `groupName` on the `URL`, but get redirected, for some reason. What is going on?

**One small Update I just deiscovered. It seems, that the URL for react-router-dom, is dropping one parameter. What I mean is this**.

On the TableOverview Screen, the URL is `localhost:3000/something/groups`,

But when I click the link it goes to `localhost:3000/groups/details/name`.
**

I am readin on Github about this issue here : https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/5870, haven't found a solid solution yet. But I can go and add `something` here:

```
pathname: `something/groups/details/${row.name}`
```

**It is a very weird solution, that I am not willing to continue. Foe development is fine, but I need to actually find a solution on this. Any input is welcomed..**

Can someone tell me what stupid thing I do here, and doesn't work. Thank you!!

Comment: If you see small typos, please don't answer them. I changed the names for the files and components because they were too revealing. The application has no typos...

Comment: Try adding `exact` here: `<Route path={``${path}/groups``} component={GroupsScreen} />` <--- `<Route exact path={``${path}/groups``} component={GroupsScreen} />`

Comment: Yeah, I, tried that. Nothing is happening. Still, the URL changes, but gets redirected...

Comment: To iterate on the amount of frustration I have regarding this, I also have a deleteRendere, for every Table row, that his the same API endpoint, calls for the row.name, and the row gets deleted just fine.